# Find column index for column with smallest sum in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `[3 x 3]` matrix in Matlab. I want to know for which column the sum of all its elements is the smallest. So specifically, i want to know what the index number is of that column.

I am thinking of doing this with a `while` loop, but is there a faster (or better) way?

---

What i'm doing right now is:

```
columnSum = sum(matrix,2);
minColumn = min(columnSum);

smallestColumn = 0;
columnNumber = 1;

while currentSum ~= minColumn
  smallestColumn = columnNumber;
  currentSum = columnSum(columnNumber);
  columnNumber = columnNumber + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrix is called `a` then this should do what you want:

```
[C,I] = min(sum(a,1))
```

I'm leaving the office now, so won't explain further, you should be able to figure it out.